# Delete all messages in a channel from my bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
channel.fetchMessages()
.then(messages => messages.array.forEach(
    message => message.author.equals(client.user) && message.delete()
));
```

Tried to do this to delete from TextChannel `channel` all messages that my bot has sent.

Doesn't work, errors:

> `messages.array.forEach` is not a function

How can I get my bot to delete all the messages my bot has sent to a specific channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.array` is a function, not just a property on the `messages` collection. Instead of using `.array`, use `.array()`. Here's the fix in your code:

```
channel.fetchMessages()
.then(messages => messages.array().forEach(
    message => message.author.equals(client.user) && message.delete()
));
```